# Hibernate how to write Detachedcriteria in 2 decimal point?

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria

Here I have 2 value example price and discountPrice.
When I using mysql

```
select price, discountPrice from stockItem where price = discountPrice;
```

I found no record.

After I changed to

```
select price, discountPrice from stockItem where FORMAT(price,2) = FORMAT(discountPrice,2);
```

I able to query the record out.

May I know in hibernate how to write Detachedcriteria in 2 decimal point?

Here the Current Code:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(StockItem.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("price", "discountPrice"));
return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Is there a way to write?

In mysql
We saw it is 10.70. I only suspect the number actual number is 10.700000000000001. Is there a way to identify this?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("FORMAT(price,2) = FORMAT(discountPrice,2)"));
```

by using sqlRestriction() you can insert literal SQL fragments right into query